# Find closest value to a given value in a dictionary c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, numbers, key-value

I have a dictionary and I want to find out which of the ‘key’ values is the closest to a given value, here is my dictionary below.

```
Dictionary<double, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<double, int>();

dictionary.Add(2.4, 5000);
dictionary.Add(6, 2000);
dictionary.Add(12, 1000);
dictionary.Add(24, 500);
dictionary.Add(60, 200);
dictionary.Add(120, 100);
dictionary.Add(240, 50);
dictionary.Add(600, 20);
dictionary.Add(1200, 10);
dictionary.Add(2400, 5);
dictionary.Add(6000, 2);
dictionary.Add(12000, 1);

givenValue = 1;
```

So I want to find out which of the keys is the closest to 1. I need the key value pair to be returned, so it should return [2.4, 5000].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you may ask yourself if a dictionary is the right structure for solving these types of problems, but assuming that this is a given (to address other concerns), you could do the following:

```
var bestMatch = dictionary.OrderBy(e => Math.Abs(e.Key - givenValue)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is going to be very inefficient, if you need to do many such queries though.

The following is a bit more efficient:

```
Tuple<double, KeyValuePair<double, int>> bestMatch = null;
foreach (var e in dictionary)
{
    var dif = Math.Abs(e.Key - givenValue);
    if (bestMatch == null || dif < bestMatch.Item1)
        bestMatch = Tuple.Create(dif, e);
}
```

Comment: @Sharped Care to explain? The first sorting solution is O(N log N), the second solution is O(N). Perhaps you are referring to the multiple allocations for the Tuple? Those could be easily prevented by keeping track of the best matching pair and smallest difference seperately.

Comment: @Sharped, perhaps you should try it, before downvoting and posting misleading comments without explanation. The linear search option (including Tuple allocations) is more than 10 times faster.

Comment: @Alex , you are right, OrderBy is O(NlogN), I removed my useless comment